# RobotFramework: empty variable check suddenly not working anymore

Tags: robotframework

I'm playing around with command-line arguments and had something working both with / without giving a command-line argument, but suddenly it starts failing if I don't give a command-line argument.

On https://groups.google.com/g/robotframework-users/c/_5Usp-K4Dlw?pli=1 I read that adding a space before the variable and comparing it to a value like this `'${ VAR}'==<value>` should work to check if a variable is existing or not.

The code-snippet that was working before is:

```
*** Test Cases ***
My test
    [Documentation]    test to check if the SUT reacts as expected
    ${is_test}=        Evaluate    '${ VAR}'=='test'
    Log To Console     ${is_test}
    Run Keyword If     ${is_test}    Log To Console    VAR == test
```

After changing the code to (Removed '[Documentation]' since it was copied from another test):

```
*** Test Cases ***
My test
    ${is_test}=        Evaluate    '${ VAR}'=='test'
    Log To Console     ${is_test}
    Run Keyword If     ${is_test}
    ...    Log To Console    VAR == test
```

it suddenly started failing with: `Variable '${ VAR}' not found.` errors.
And after changing it back to the original it still fails.

I can't figure what I did wrong in the change.

Note: The company I'm working for uses RobotFramework version 3.0.4 (yes I know ancient)

Comment: You could put the condition straight into the if `Run Keyword If     '${VAR}'=='test'`. Also if you do not pass this variable from command line and you do not have it in the `***Variable***` then it won't exist. Did not you have it passed from command line when it worked earlier?

Comment: @BenceKaulics: It somehow did work the first time I tried it without any ```***Variable***``` set and not passing the argument on the command line.
But from your comment I conclude that it not supposed to work that way ;-) Thanx again.

Comment: Btw. I put it outside the ```Run Keyword If``` since in the final script we have 2 possible paths:
1 which should be taken when VAR==test and another one if that evaluates to False (so I had to put that in a ```Run Keyword Unless``` section with the same conditional check).

Comment: I've never heard of the trick to use `${ VAR}`. If it worked, it was probably by accident. It's certainly not a documented feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by adding `${VAR}` with some default value to a `*** Variables ***` list. But still I don't understand why it was originally working without that list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your test should look like if you want to check if variable is empty and do something based on that.

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR}=    test

*** Test Cases ***
My test
    Run Keyword If    '${VAR}'=='${EMPTY}'    Log To Console    Variable is empty
    ...    ELSE    Log To Console    Variable is not empty
```

If you want variable default value to be empty and execute some keyword only if it comes from command line set variable as empty, for example:

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR}=    ${EMPTY}

*** Test Cases ***
My test
    Run Keyword If    '${VAR}'=='${EMPTY}'    Log To Console    Variable is not set
    ...    ELSE    Log To Console    Variable is ${VAR}
```

Run your test from command-line without passing variable

```
$ robot sample.robot 
==============================================================================
Sample                                                                        
==============================================================================
My test                                                               Variable is not set
My test                                                               | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sample                                                                | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Now, run with passing variable

```
$ robot -v VAR:test sample.robot 
==============================================================================
Sample                                                                        
==============================================================================
My test                                                               Variable is test
My test                                                               | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sample                                                                | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

P.S. About space inside variable, I think it's just typo in Google Groups. If it was working then variable might be globally accessible or defined somewhere else.